# How to create dynamic-named instance DynamicObject

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamic

How to create dynamic-named instance of my PersonObject class

Not like this

```
dynamic variable1 = new PersonObject();
variable1.PropertyName = value;
```

But like this

```
dynamic variable1 = new PersonObject();
variable1[DynamicPropertyName] = value;
```

Where DynamicPropertyName is my string variable

My code is:

```
using System.Dynamic;

class PersonObject : DynamicObject, IInterface
{
    Dictionary<string, object> members = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 
    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        members[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (members.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = members[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        dynamic method = members[binder.Name];
        result = method((int)args[0]);
        return result != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add indexer to the PersonObject class.

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get { return members[key]; }
    set { members[key] = value; }
}
```